# Selective threading of the Rule

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

How can I change **form1** to **form2**

#### form1

```
{10000, 10004} -> {2, 2, 637}
```

#### form2

```
{10000 -> {2, 2, 637}, 10004 -> {2, 2, 637}}
```

#### One of my solutions

```
(Thread[MapThread[((*f/@*)#1 -> g@#2) &,   
                  List /@ List[{10000, 10004}, {2, 2, 637}]
                 ][[1]]
       ]) //. g -> Part
```

> ```
>    {10000->{2,2,637},10004->{2,2,637}}
> ```

Have I taken a little detour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the third argument for `Thread`:

```
Thread[ {10000, 10004} -> {2, 2, 637},  List, 1]
```

> ```
> {10000 -> {2, 2, 637}, 10004 -> {2, 2, 637}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = {10000, 10004} -> {2, 2, 637};
# -> l[[2]] & /@ l[[1]]
(* {10000 -> {2, 2, 637}, 10004 -> {2, 2, 637}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us define:

```
 form1 = {10000, 10004} -> {2, 2, 637};
f[x_] := x -> form1[[2]];
```

Then the second form is

```
 f /@ f1[[1]]

(*  {10000 -> {2, 2, 637}, 10004 -> {2, 2, 637}}  *)
```

Have fun!